# SPAMHAUSを使ったスパムメール判定の方法について

Tags: mail

【問題】
SPAMHAUSのスパムメール送信者リストへの問い合わせコマンドが正しく実行できません。

【経緯】
メール送信者のIPアドレスから、スパムメールかどうかを判定する方法を探しています。
調査の結果、メール送信者のIPアドレスをSPAMHAUSのデータベースに問い合わせる方法があることがわかりました。
SPAMHAUS公式サイトのFAQのほか、いくつかのサイトを参考にしたところ、コマンドとして、

```
dig +short [問い合わせたいIPアドレス].zen.spamhaus.org
```

を実行すれば良いものだと思っているのですが、返り値が表示されず、正しい実行結果が表示されません。

---

やってみたこと１
1. 迷惑メールの危険性及び送信元アドレスのドメインとリンク先ドメイン一覧：
　　https://brionac-yu-yake.net/spam-mail/
　　こちらのサイトを参考に、スパムメールを送信していそうなドメインを探す
　　（例：iphonexstv.com）。
2. １のドメインをnslookupコマンドの引数にして、IPアドレスを得る（103.242.7.XXX）。
3. SPAMHAUSのブラックリスト解除センターで２のIPアドレスを入力する。
4. Lookupボタンを押下し、２のIPアドレスがリストに入っていることを確認する
　　（103.242.7.XXX is listed in the SBL）。
5. コマンド、`dig +short 103.242.7.XXX.zen.spamhaus.org` を実行する。
6. 実行結果は何も出力されず、コマンドラインには次の入力行が表示される。

やってみたこと２

1. SPAMHAUSのFAQsページを参考に、

   ```
   dig +short @103.242.7.XXX 2.0.0.127.zen.spamhaus.org
   ```

   コマンドを実行する。
2. `;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached` と出力される

※上記やってみたこと１，２において、XXXはマスクのための文字列で、実際には数字を入力しています。

コマンド自体に誤りがあるのだと思いますが、検索して出てくるサイトを参照してもやってみたこと１と同様のコマンドが書かれており、困っています。
どなたか正しいコマンドをご存知の方いらっしゃいましたら、ご教示いただけますと嬉しいです。

Comment: digコマンドを調べてから実行したほうがよろしいかと思います。digにおける@についてはネームサーバの指定です。問い合わせしたいIPを乗せるものではないです。

Answer (score 1):

DNSチェックをする場合はIPは逆にする必要があります
103.242.7.XXX
であれば
XXX.7.242.103.zen.spamhaus.org
がチェックするべきDNSです。

https://www.spamhaus.org/faq/section/DNSBL%20Usage#366

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
IPをそのまま打っていました。
早速IPの記載を正してみましたが、出力が得られません。
たとえば、
dig +short 1.0.0.127.zen.spamhaus.org
とコマンドを入力すれば、（スパムメール送信者の）リストに存在ない場合でも
Host 1.0.0.127.zen.spamhaus.org not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
と出力されるものだと思っていたのですが、この認識は間違っている（リストにないIPならば出力はないのが正しい）のでしょうか。

Comment: digのshortオプションは一致する値が無ければ何も返しません。spamhaus以外のドメイン（stackoverflow.com等）で試してみてください。

Comment: すみません、digコマンドをよく調べもせず試行していました。
+shortオプションを外すと出力が確認できました。
「->>HEADER<<-」行に'status: NXDOMAIN'と表示されます。
これがスパムメール送信者リストに存在しないことを表しているのでしょうか。
公式のブロックリスト削除センター（Blocklist Removal Center）でSBLリストに載っていることが確認できたIPアドレスでも同様の状態になることが気にかかります。
ひとまずまったく手がかりのない状態から一歩進むことができました、ありがとうございます。